# Can I disallow purchases on my Xbox 360 even when I have points available?

Tags: xbox-360

On my Xbox 360 I have my account sign on automatically so that others in the household can watch Netflix.  But I've noticed that now my account has 0 points because my 3 year old has purchased random stuff accidentally.

Is there a way to put points on my Live account but do something like password protect only the purchases?

Xbox support has been terribly unhelpful and hasn't given me a straight answer, so I'm guessing there's no way.

Comment: be glad you don't have your credit card linked too: http://www.almightydad.com/parenting/xbox-parental-controls-good-idea-in-hindsight

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this Xbox support page](http://support.xbox.com/en-us/pages/xbox-live/how-to/parental-control.aspx), you can use the parental controls to restrict purchases, but only for a *child* account.

I'm not at home and can't verify this right now, but you should be able to create a new profile, designate it as a child account, and set *that* profile to sign in automatically. You can switch to your main profile when you want to make a purchase or play a game.

Not an optimal solution, but it's all I can think of.

Comment: You can probably also link said child account to your net flix account, so people will still be able to watch net flix, but will be locked from spending points.

Comment: Then set said child account as the auto-logon. It'll be less convenient for you, since you'll have to manually logon, but it'll protect your points. :)

Comment: Regarding Netflix: If the child account is created, doesn't that account have to be a Gold account to access the Netflix service? Netflix is only available to Xbox Live Gold members.

Comment: @Blake, yes, it would have to be a Gold account ... so either way (standalone or Family Pack) it would involve two separate Gold accounts.